# Shebang line and batch files for pythonw to run background process

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-10, shebang, pythonw

I normally use the following shebang line and batch file format for my scripts on **Windows 10**

```
#!python

@py c:path\to\script.py %*
```

How must I change these to run pythonw?

Thanks

Comment: `script.pyw` perhaps?

Comment: Do I also need to change the Shebang line to #!pythonw ?

Comment: Or perhaps `@"F:\ull\Path\To\pythonw.exe" "C:\path\to\script.py" %*`

Comment: I would suggest you have a [look](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)... Enjoy :)